# Xamarin Modal don't wait

Tags: c#, xamarin, modal-dialog

I tried to insert a Modal Page in my App.

Now I post an Example. Only an Example

```
await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyModalPage());
await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
```

I don't understand why my app don't wait after `myModalpage` has been loaded.
Also I have tried to insert an
`await DispleayAlert(....)`  row after my second `PushModalAsync`
and I see this alert without waiting.

Comment: Do you expect it to wait until the modal is dismissed? That is not how the API works. It just continue as soon as it is done pushing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Cheesebaron said:

> That is not how the API works. It just continue as soon as it is done
> pushing.

The method did await and I think it performs too fast so that you feel like it does not await.

You can add some custom delay to make it slower. It only wait until the page pop up.

```
public async void test()
{

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());
}
```